# Pass Column to Function where the column can be empty

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to pass a column to a function where sometimes the column passed can be empty or blank.

For example

```
def test (df,segment):
  score_df = df \
  .withColumn('model_segment', when(lit(segment) =='',lit('')).otherwise(col(segment)))
  return score_df
```

This works

```
test(df,'my_existing_column').show()
```

However this errors

```
test(df,'').show()
```

This errors with the message cannot resolve '``' given input columns

I get why it is doing that, but how would I go about handling this kind of scenario?

Comment: Just add a check in your `test` func: `if segment in df.columns: ...`

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of dataframe fields by df.columns,then check whether the incoming parameter exists in the field list, if it exists, execute show action, otherwise trigger a custom exception that the field does not exist.